# Function wont execute after pagination

Tags: jquery, html, css, pagination

This is the project i am working on. If you click on BLOGS [on my site](http://www.singhharmeet.com/akhileshsir/) then the posts will show. Now if you click the post the full view of that particular post will be displayed. But, since i applied the simple pagination on the blog posts page, the full post view will only work on the first page. Following is the pagination loop:

```
jQuery('#Pagination a').live('click', function(e) { //check when pagination link is clicked and stop its action.
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = jQuery(this).attr('href'); //Get the href attribute
    jQuery('#pcontent').fadeOut(500, function() { //fade out the content area
        jQuery("#loader").show(); // show the loader animation
    }).load(link + ' #pcontent', function() {
        jQuery("#loader").hide();
        jQuery('#pcontent').fadeIn(500, function() { //load data from the content area from paginator link page that we just get from the top
            //hide the loader
        });
    });
});
```

The full page post view is simple jquery show hide (hide everything else and show the detailed post).

Comment: Did you know that you only have to write `jQuery` in its long form once? By wrapping your code in `(function($) { .... })(jQuery);`, you can use `$` no matter if `noConflict` has been used or not.

Comment: Nope i didn't. I am fairly new to jQuery but thanks will surely implement this method from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I can't find the js piece that loads the full post that fast, but you've probably binded the click functionality with ie. the `click` or `bind` function. But those handlers aren't attached when new ajax content is loaded (using the pagination). Use the `on` or `live` functions instead.

NB; do you realise that users with a low-height (read: laptop) screen can't see the pagination because there is no scroll bar?

Comment: Currently the post is just a static div that is being loaded. Once i deal with this pagination issue i will bring in the posts dynamically. I applied the live(change) and it worked thanks. And yes i know, all the css issues/bugs will be removed at the end. Thanks for help guys.